# Querying immediately for saved entity returns null sometimes - datastore

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am saving an entity kind 'review' with following properties

```
review {
  _id : 4e0590ae-7603-44ff-8333-b3d06546914f
  text : 'Nice review'
}
```

I am saving it with a AJAX call and on success response I am passing `_id` and querying for saved review in another AJAX call. Sometimes I am getting null which results in NullPointerException. In datastore storing entity takes more time? If takes then the first AJAX call should not return till put operation completes. Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In datastore, you don't have instantaneous strong consistency. You have eventual consistency while your data replicates and your indices get populated.

To force consistency, you need either [ancestor queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor), or [get-by-key queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_by_id).

Look up [this article](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/) for more ideas on how to structure your data.

Comment: Thanks. I am modelling my domain classes such a way that switching to cassandra should also work.. So, I have to change the way to avoid using ancestor queries and get-by-key queries.

Comment: Then you'll need to wait, there's no other way to force consistency, as far as I know.